# Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile intermittently returning null

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm using android 4.0.4, kernel 3.0.8+

Every so often BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns a null bitmap.

Note that if the bitmap factory fails to load the bitmap I immediately try again, up to 4 times, and this often works (!)

There are a lot of people complaining about this. Most of the questions have answers involving where the bitmap is put, or the nature of the flushed input stream / http connection / whatever.  I have ruled these out - in fact, I have reduced my problem to an android application of such ridiculous simplicity that it could be called a test case.

My app has a single activity, which contains a single button, which when pushed starts a thread that loops through the external files directory trying to load everything in it into bitmaps.  I don't use the bitmap, or keep it, or anything, I just load and forget:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = "bmpbash";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  public void onGo(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    start();
  }

  /**
   * Start the thread.
   */
  public void start() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        mainLoop();
      }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
  }

  public void mainLoop() {
    int index = 0;
    File top = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    while (true) {
      File[] files = top.listFiles();
      if (files.length < 1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "no files found");
      } else {
        if (files.length <= index) {
          index = 0;
        }
        File file = files[index];

        //byte[] data = readFile(file);

        try {
          boolean ok = false;
          for (int i = 0; i < 4 && !ok; ++i) {
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if (bitmap == null) {
              Log.e(TAG, file.getName() + "[" + i + "] - NULL bitmap");
            } else {
              ok = true;
              Log.w(TAG, file.getName() + "[" + i + "] - OK");
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, file.getName() + " - DIED", e);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
          Log.e(TAG, file.getName() + " - OOM");
        }
        ++index;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I will see output like this:

```
10-22 17:27:57.688: W/bmpbash(1131): translucent.png[0] - OK
10-22 17:27:57.698: W/bmpbash(1131): fearthecow.png[0] - OK
10-22 17:27:57.798: W/bmpbash(1131): gui2.png[0] - OK
10-22 17:27:57.888: W/bmpbash(1131): gui.png[0] - OK
10-22 17:27:58.058: W/bmpbash(1131): boot.png[0] - OK
10-22 17:27:58.218: E/bmpbash(1131): trainer2.png[0] - NULL bitmap
10-22 17:27:58.378: W/bmpbash(1131): trainer2.png[1] - OK
```

You will see in the above code there is a commented out alternative load sequence, in which rather than using decodeFile I load the file into a byte[] and then use decodeByteArray.  This has the same effect (decodeByteArray fails and then immediately succeeds on exactly the same byte array!), but I do note that the failures are much less common.

In the decodeFile case, perhaps 1 in 10 attempts returns null.  In the decodeByteArray case, perhaps only 1 in 100.  It is not always the same file that fails, but some files do *seem* to fail more often than others.

My best hunch is that the png decoder has a failure which is more likely to occur if it runs over a longer period of time, but after that I'm a bit lost.  If anyone has any light to shed on the issue, or alternative approaches to loading png files, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I should have said - right before a null bitmap is reported I see the skia information message "--- decoder->decode returned false"

Comment: I am facing the same issue and don't have any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Further experiments show that this occurs on every device I have (I have quite a lot) which is running a particular flavour of 4.0.4, but does not occur even if left running overnight on a 4.1.1 device.  Given the simplicity of the code, and that a later android version doesn't replicate it, my inclination is to mark this as a bug in Android which has, at some point, been fixed.  With that information to help, I am going to assume that this is a bug in SKIA which is argued about to the nth degree in this thread here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

My overall opinion is that this is a rarely occurring bug the existence of which is obscured by the enormous number of people who don't handle their input streams carefully enough.  The only answer I've seen anywhere for *this* problem is to attempt to load the bitmap in a loop (OMG).  However, if the hundreds of people who find this question because they have these *symptoms* could please make 100% sure that they are using a viable flushed input stream before resorting to such an unholy hack, then I think we'd all appreciate it!

Thanks

P.S. is it OK to feel guilty about calling this an "answer" ?

Comment: I have confirmation - I have a device crash log showing SIGSEGV (signal 11) in libskia while decoding a png.  It rebooted the entire device this time, instead of returning null.  There is something seriously wrong with it.  I don't suppose anyone can recommend a stable firmware image for A10 devices that *isn't* 4.0.4 can they?

Comment: Aaaaaand I'm revoking my own answer.  I've now seen this fail on a 4.2.2 device.  I'm thinking this is not a "Java" or "Android" bug anymore, but instead a device driver / kernel level problem on some devices.

Comment: I have little motivation to try to solve this now, so I will tidy up this question with what I know and abandon it. My best bet is that this is a bug in AllWinner devices, and related to their claim to have hardware decoding of png files.  I do not observe the problem with JPEG, and I do not observe the problem on rockchip devices.  AllWinner responded to me with a fairly routine set of questions and then forgot I exist, so I can't confirm anything or fix anything.  I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar but I solved it just by adding access permission to the external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pretty sure I would always fail or always succeed if I got permissions wrong, not randomly one or the other ...